# Script to Detect Remote Computer Reboot and Reconnect Network Folder

Tags: windows, detect, reboot

I have beens searching with little success on this problem. We have a setup with four Windows 7 computers. Three computers get information from a fourth main computer. Recently, there was an issue where this fourth "master" computer needed to be rebooted, and we had to manually reconnect the other three computers back to the networked folder, as they are useless without this.

Is there any way to have these three computers detect when the fourth one reboots, and have each of the three run a script to reconnect to the network drive?

I have found information on reconnecting to networked drives when the computer is rebooted, but these three computers are always on, so it didn't help as much as I hoped. What I am talking about can be found below:

1. Three computers monitor the state of the fourth, "master" computer.
2. If they detect the fourth computer is offline, or has rebooted, they each run a script to reconnect to a specific networked folder.

I apologize about the lack of script on my part, as I am unfamiliar with this, but am working to learn it as quickly as possible. If anyone has any ideas, or knows of articles that may help, I would greatly appreciate it.